# passing options from an array to built in ls command in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell-script, options

I am writing a shell script that takes several args like `-l -s -a -f thing ming` and append only those starting with `-`.

This is my code:

```
arrayOfArgs=() 
for arg in "$@":
do
    case arg in 
    -*) arrayofArgs+=($args) ;;
    esac
 done
```

Now my `arrayOfArgs` print this

```
-l, -s, -a, -f.
```

The thing I am worried about is that the result is separated by the comma.

is  `ls {"$arrayOfArgs"}`  equivalent to   `ls -l -s -a -f` ?

Comment: The commas will mess it up. Have you tried piping it into `awk -F , '{print $1$2$3$4}'`? That will ouput `-l -s -a -f`.

Comment: `arrayofArgs+=($args) ;;` ... there is not `args` variable, and you haven't shown us how you printed `arrayofArgs`, so there's no telling how the comma got there. Please show us what you're actually running.

Comment: @muru when I print an array, it is empty.

Comment: Of course it's empty. You read the command line into `arg` but assign the array from `args` (so you basically assign empty values to `arrayofArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to solve the question you've asked, this answer offers a solution that attempts to solve the underlying issue. For this example I've assumed that arguments `a` and `s` are booleans (switches) but argument `l` takes a parameter:

```
unset -v flagA flagS valueL
while getopts "al:s" OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        a)    echo "Got a"; flagA=true ;;
        s)    echo "Got s"; flagS=true ;;
        l)    printf 'Got l with value "%s"\n' "$OPTARG"; valueL="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

printf '%s\n' "flagA=${flagA-unset}, flagS=${flagS-unset}, valueL=${valueL-unset}"
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  printf 'Other arguments:\n'
  printf ' - "%s"\n' "$@"
fi
```

More information in the `bash` man page.